# Variation on the Cauchy mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

From Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th edition, problem 11-50:

> Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable
>   on $(a,b)$, and $g'(x)\neq 0$ for $x$ in $(a,b)$, then there is some
>   $x$ in $(a,b)$ with $$\frac{f'(x)} {g'(x)} = \frac {f(x) - f(a)}
>  {g(b)-g(x)}.$$ **Hint**: Multiply out first, to see what this really
>   says.

I've struggled with this one for a while, to no avail. I'm sure it's just something small I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Rolle's theorem to

$$\phi(x) = [f(x)-f(a)][g(b)-g(x)].$$

We have

$$\phi(a) = \phi(b) = 0$$

and $\phi$ is differentiable on (a,b) with

$$\phi'(x) = f'(x)[g(b)-g(x)] - g'(x)[f(x)- f(a)].$$

There is a point in $(a,b)$ where $\phi'(x) = 0$.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that we can divide by $g(b)-g(x)$ because $g$ is injective.

Comment: @Eric Auld: Excellent point -- I was just looking at that ratio -- and that finishes it.